# Is there a way to define a getter function in C# as ReadOnly like VB.NET?

Tags: c#

In C#, it is possible to define a `readonly` getter function by not defining the set function like so:

```
private int _id;

public int Id
{

   get { return _id; }
   // no setter defined
}
```

in VB.NET

```
Private _id as Integer
Public Readonly Property Id() As Integer
    Get
       Return _id
    End Get
End Property
```

Is it possible to tag such a function as `readonly` like you can in VB .NET in order to be more verbose?

Comment: In order to be more verbose?!  That's what vb is for...

Comment: When you say "more verbose" what are you referring to? With your code example, you would get the same compiler error as you would in VB.NET if you tried to assign to it. Intellisense should also identify it as a gettable only item.

Comment: @Jonathan: More verbose in that it is clearer to the reader rather than through inference that it is a readonly property.

Comment: The absence of a setter makes it perfectly clear that the property is read-only...

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I know but if there was a way to tag it as readonly it would be nice. Comments will have to suffice for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know what the `ReadOnly` gives you in VB.  I guess the most explicit you can get is actually less verbose:

```
public int Id { get; private set; }
```

In C#, `readonly` indicates that a field's value is set during creation of the object and is unchangeable after the constructor exits.  You could achieve that via:

```
private readonly int _id; // note field marked as 'readonly'

public int Id
{
   get { return _id; }
}
```

Unfortunately automatic properties (like I show in the first code snippet) are not allowed to be `readonly`.  That is, you must enforce read-only semantics yourself by ensuring that none of your class's code calls the private setter after the constructor exits.  I guess this is different to what you're referring to by VB's usage of `ReadOnly` though.

**EDIT** As Thomas points out, having no getter is different from having a private one.  However [VB's usage of `ReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b2c2ka.aspx) is different to the C# one, at least when used with properties:

```
' Only code inside class employee can change the value of hireDateValue.
Private hireDateValue As Date
' Any code that can access class employee can read property dateHired.
Public ReadOnly Property dateHired() As Date
    Get
        Return hireDateValue
    End Get
End Property
```

To a C# programmer, the `ReadOnly` keyword would seem redundant.  It is already implied by the fact that no setter exists.

As far as fields are concerned, C# and VB seem equivalent.

Comment: Having a private setter is not the same as no setter at all... It just means the setter can only be accessed from inside the class. Such a property is read-only from the outside only